# Best Practice for combining arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this code for creating an array object, I wanted to know what are the best practices for doing this and I am trying to learn php best practices.

```
$authorId = array("1", "2");
$authorName = array("Juan Cruz", "Jose Rizal");
$authorSname = array("J. Cruz", "J. Rizal");

for ($i = 0; $i < count($authorId); $i++) {
  array_push($authorValue, array(
     "author_id" => $authorId[$i],
     "author_name" => $authorName[$i],
     "author_sname" => $authorSname[$i],
  ));
}
```

and also this will be the result of this code converted into JSON.

```
[
    {
        "author_id": "1",
        "author_name": "Juan Cruz",
        "author_sname": "J. Cruz"
    },
    {
        "author_id": "2",
        "author_name": "Jose Rizal",
        "author_sname": "J. Rizal"
    }
]
```

Comment: Can the array element be arrays instead of object? is so, `array_map` can do that easily

Comment: no, the thing is the values will be accessed using foreach in javascript.

Comment: There's no specific "best practice" for this. You can do it in multiple ways, but as long as it works, go for it. There's nothing wrong with the above code.

Comment: _"for creating an array object"_ - You're not creating "array objects", you're creating a multidimensional array. In PHP, it's all just arrays.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks. Yes it works I am just thinking of another way that is easier to understand and remember.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code works, The OP just want us to review it. It should be posted over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead since SO is for when you're having _issues_ with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using:

```
$authorId = array("1", "2");
$authorName = array("Juan Cruz", "Jose Rizal");
$authorSname = array("J. Cruz", "J. Rizal");

$keys = array("author_id", "author_name", "author_sname");
$res = array_map(null, $authorId, $authorName, $authorSname);
$res = array_map(function ($e) use ($keys) {return json_encode(array_combine($keys, $e), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);}, $res);
```

Use the JSON_FORCE_OBJECT to convert to json

Reference: [array-combine](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php), [array-map](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Comment: I am using json_encode is JSON_FORCE_OBJECT better?

Comment: @rektph - With the JSON_FORCE_OBJECT flag, even the array that contains the objects would become an object: `{"0": {"author_id": '', ...}, "1": {"author_id": ...}}`. That's not a good structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_map`

```
$res = [];
$key=0;
array_map(function($v1,$v2,$v3) use(&$res,&$key){
    $res[] = [
     'author_id'   => $v1,
     'author_name' => $v2, 
     'author_sname'=> $v3
  ];
 $key++;
}, $authorId,$authorName,$authorSname);
echo json_encode($res);
```

[Live Demo](https://3v4l.org/lTBup)

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer but I think the answer is the easiest to remember.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the Fastest easy way

```
<?php

$authorId = array("1", "2");
$authorName = array("Juan Cruz", "Jose Rizal");
$authorSname = array("J. Cruz", "J. Rizal");
$res = [];
foreach($authorId as $key => $value){
    $res[] = [
        'author_id'   => $value,
        'author_name' => $authorName[$key], 
        'author_sname'=> $authorSname[$key]
    ];
}
echo json_encode($res);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/8pY6u)